How to enable python includes when EXECing from PHP
I have a small python script for calculating the peaks of a PPG signal, as below.
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# Sample PPG signal
ppg_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*0.5*np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)) + np.random.rand(1000) * 0.2

# Find peaks with prominence of 0.1 and minimum distance of 20 samples
peaks, _ = find_peaks(ppg_signal, prominence=0.1, distance=20)

# Print the peak locations
print("Done")

This works fine in CLI mode on my server. However, when I execute it from my php script with:
exec('/usr/bin/python3 /mypython/peaks.py', $output, $ret_code);

I get a ret_code of 1 and a null output array.  If I comment it all out except the import line and the print line, it works. I have deduced that it is the 'from scipy...' line that breaks.
My guess is that it has something to do with permissions? What else can I try?
EDIT: I know that find_peaks requires a scipy update which I did install. That's why it works from command line. Just not from php exec.
EDIT2: Turns out it is the paths. My web user doesn't have the path to the scipy library enabled. I installed scipy as root. Just need to figure out how to solve that.

Without seeing your permissions, I can just take a wild guess and say its missing execution rights for group/others which can be fixed with chmod 755 /mypython/peaks.py which gives rwxr-xr-x

The script gets executed! So it isn't file permissions on the py file. It is the call within to include a python library module that is failing.

Perhaps this is the right time to be using venv if you rely on packages you don't want to install per user or globally
